# Can create-react-app be used with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

Is it possible to use TypeScript with `create-react-app`? If so, how would you do it?

Comment: what would prevent you from doing so ?

Comment: I [think its possible](https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript), but I personally wouldn't use JavaScript for anything more thant manipulation my client's browsers DOM.

Comment: @WilomGfx In response to "what would prevent you from doing so": in the past I would add some entries to webpack.config.js telling webpack to compile the typescript as part of the build process. With create-react-app, webpack is hidden. There is no place to configure stuff.

Comment: You have to run the eject script

Answer (score 50):

You can do it like this:

```
create-react-app my-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

See https://github.com/wmonk/create-react-app-typescript

No ejecting required for this.

Comment: This now seems to be officially supported by Microsoft: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-React-Starter

Comment: @bfncs I would watch out though, doesn't seem like this repo is maintained very well (this also comes back in the open issues)

Comment: Check the more recent answer from Martin, as ts is now supported by CRA directly.

Answer (score 20):

This is the way to go:

```
# update create-react-app first
npm update -g create-react-app 
create-react-app my-app --typescript
```

[Create React App v2.1.0](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v2.1.0) now supports TypeScript, so you no longer need to eject or use the `react-scripts-ts` fork;

Or you can [add TypeScript to the existing app](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript):

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
# or
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

then rename `.js` files to `.tsx` files to start using TypeScript.

Note that a tsconfig.json will be created for you when you run the app. You will be able to edit tsconfig.json except for [some options](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/87e3d4fd1080d290f675d0461e3d3656752628ab/packages/react-scripts/scripts/utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup.js#L105-L129).

Credits:

[1] [Vincent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53063071/2724342)

[2] [migrate create react app typescript](https://vincenttunru.com/migrate-create-react-app-typescript-to-create-react-app/) post

Answer (score 7):

Typescript is available out of the box now, in create-react-app version 2.1!

You can use it now, like this ([as shown here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/5550#issuecomment-433463527)):

`npx create-react-app@next app-name --scripts-version=2.0.6-next.c662dfb0 --typescript`

Comment: It'll be in v2.1 https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/milestone/57

Comment: Try `npx create-react-app@next app-name --scripts-version=2.0.6-next.c662dfb0 --typescript`

-- That's from a comment from this PR: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/5550

Comment: Please note we do not recommend you start using the beta until 2.1 is fully out. There will still be breaking changes.

Comment: Update: 2.1 is out now! https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases. So this should work: `npx create-react-app@2.1 app-name --typescript`

Answer (score 3):

**Here is update about `create-react-app` `--typescript` flag**

Previously in order to generate new project in typescript with `create-react-app` we used `typescript` flag like below

```
npx create-react-app my-app --typescript
```

But this `typescript` flag will be removed in next major release of `create-react-app` as mentioned in the `create-react-app --help`

> ```
>   --typescript (this option will be removed in favor of templates in the next major release of create-react-app)
> ```

So the new solution will be to use a template as mentioned [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#custom-templates)

ex:

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

Comment: Here's the same answer in video format [create react app with typescript](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MWpmPP4z8HE)

Answer (score 2):

I posted a feature request in the github issues for create-react-app and here was the response:

> Hi! We're not quite ready to consider TypeScript yet (see #142 for
>   updates). We have yet to complete our Flow integration (which we will
>   suggest as first option for type safety).
>
> Additionally, there's really interesting things going on right now.
>   See babel/babylon#320 and babel/babylon#444. TypeScript may soon be
>   parsed by Babylon (and compiled by Babel). Microsoft has interest in
>   seeing this happen, and are working on a WIP themselves, too.
>
> This consideration is probably still a few months out. Sorry!
>
> Though unendorsed by us, there is a fork of CRA which supports
>   TypeScript. We cannot provide support if it doesn't work for you, but
>   it should!

Not sure how to square that with levito's response.

Here is the link to the github issue:

https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/issues/1998#issuecomment-295311100

Answer (score 2):

You can use Facebook's Official [Typescript Template](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/cra-template-typescript) for Create React App.

Do

```
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

or

```
yarn create react-app my-app --template typescript
```

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can create your app using this [starter](https://github.com/vtereshyn/react-typescript-eslint-starter) (https://github.com/vtereshyn/react-typescript-eslint-starter)

It doesn't use create-react-app, so fully customizable and changeable. Because using create-react-app it will be hard to add something in some cases...