# Migrating create-react-app from javascript to typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I started a react project using create-react-app few months ago and I'm interesting in migrating the project from Javascript to Typescript.

I saw that there is a way to create react app with typescript using the flag:

```
--scripts-version=react-scripts-ts
```

But I didn't find any explanation how can I migrate an existing JS project to TS.
I need it to be done incrementally so I can work with both .js and .ts files so I can do the transformation over time.
Does anyone has any experience with this migration? What are the required steps that should be done to make this work?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**UPDATE:** create-react-app version 2.1.0 support typescript so for those of you who are starting from scratch you can use it to create new application with typescript, and according to the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v2.1.0) it should be done with the following command:

```
$ npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

For existing projects, after updating to version 2.1.0, add the following packages to your project's dependencies with the following command:

```
$ npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

and then you can simply rename .js to .ts files.

---

I found a solution to migrate create-react-app from javascript to typescript, this way **doesn't require** eject.

1. Create a temporary react project with typescript by running the command `create-react-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts`
   (Note - requires `create-react-app` to be installed globally)
2. In your own project - under `package.json` file remove the `react-scripts`
3. Add `react-scripts-ts` to your project by running the command `yarn add react-scripts-ts` or if your are using npm then `npm install react-scripts-ts`. Or, add `"react-scripts-ts": "2.8.0"` to package.json.
4. From the project you created in step 1 copy the files: `tsconfig.json, tsconfig.test.json tslint.json` to your own project
5. Under your own project, in `package.json`, under scripts section, change `react-scripts` instances to `react-scripts-ts` (should be under `start`, `build`, `test` and `eject`
6. Install the typings for react by installing the following modules using yarn or npm: `@types/node`, `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom`. Put in `devDependencies` section if using package.json.
7. Change `index.js` file name to `index.tsx`
8. In your tsconfig.json file add the following configuration: `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` - [for more info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html)

**NOTE** step 7 might require additional modification depends on what you have in your index.js file (if it depends on JS modules in the project).

Now you can run your project and it might work, for those of you who are getting error that contains `You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type` regarding .js files, it happens because babel doesn't know how to load .js file from .tsx files. What we need to do is to change the project configuration. The way I found doing it without running `eject` is using [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired) package. This package lets you configure external configuration which will be added/override the default project settings. What we'll do is using babel to load these type of files. Let's moved on:

1. Install the package `react-app-rewired` using yarn or npm
2. In your root folder (where `package.json` is located) create a new file with the name `config-overrides.js`
3. Put this code in `config-overrides` file:

   ```
   var paths = require('react-scripts-ts/config/paths')

   module.exports = function override(config) {
     config.module.rules.push({
       test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
       include: paths.appSrc,
       loader: require.resolve('babel-loader'),
       options: {
           babelrc: false,
           presets: [require.resolve('babel-preset-react-app')],
           cacheDirectory: true,
       },
     })

     return config
   }
   ```

Edit package.json so the `start/start-js`, `build`, `test`, and `eject` scripts use react-app-rewired as shown in the [project readme](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired#2-custom-scripts-versions). E.g. `"test": "react-app-rewired test --scripts-version react-scripts-ts --env=jsdom"`.

Now you can start you the project and the problem should be solved. You might need additional modifications depending on your project (additional types and so).

Hope it helps

As suggested here in the comments, it's possible to define: `"compilerOptions": { "allowJs": true}` in your tsconfig.json file, so you can mix JS and TS without react-app-rewired. Thanks for mention this!

Comment: I believe that the command in section 1 should read: `create-react-app --scripts-version=react-scripts-ts` (the current answer is missing an 's'). I would edit the post, but apparently I have to change 6 or more characters and I don't want to interfere.

Comment: For 8. you could add `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` to tsconfig.json

Comment: @galvan Please accept my suggestion to update two things:
As mentioned above, step 8. is not needed anymore with `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true` and also it's possible to define: `"compilerOptions": { "allowJs": true},` so that you can intertwin JS and TS without `react-app-rewired` part :) Other than that it's amazing tutorial :)

Comment: For step 5: My app had already implemented react-app-rewired. So I had to change the lines like so:  From `"start": "react-app-rewired start",` to `"start": "react-app-rewired start --scripts-version react-scripts-ts",`

Comment: For step 4: To avoid errors with 'npm run build', also copy `tsconfig.prod.json`

Comment: getting an error saying `Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'` - although I have run `npm i -g typescript`. Any ideas? Also for point 1 can you confirm that you also need to give the project a name as that command doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you have typescript module under devDependecies? (inside pacakge.json file)

Comment: Its still not as fast as with the babel config.

Answer (score 37):

Create React App [v2.1.0 was released today with TypeScript support](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/releases/tag/v2.1.0) today. That means you no longer need to eject or use the `react-scripts-ts` fork; [all you need to do](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript) if you have an existing Create React App project is install the required packages:

```
$ npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
$ # or
$ yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

You can then simply rename `.js` files to `.ts` files to start using TypeScript.

(If you have an existing app using the create-react-app-typescript fork, here's a tutorial on [how to port it to regular Create React App](https://vincenttunru.com/migrate-create-react-app-typescript-to-create-react-app/).)

Comment: This should be the way to go. Thank @Vincent!

Comment: I wonder why they didn't use the babel config. Its almost instantaneous.

Comment: @SILENT I'm not sure what you mean. When you use TypeScript in CRA, it does still use Babel for transpilation. TypeScript only does the type checking.

Comment: @Vincent As far as I can tell, they aren't using the babel 7's plugin preset-typescript - https://iamturns.com/typescript-babel/

Comment: @SILENT They are! See this line in the PR that added TypeScript support: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/pull/4837/files#diff-7482288d6d13860f434d0b8171f20431R105

Comment: @Vincent Thats weird. Its slower than my manually created version with babel. Maybe they aren't having typescript run in async for type checking.

Comment: I think they do, using fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin. They also do a *lot* of other stuff, though, so there's a lot of things that could be the reason.

Comment: I added typescript to my existing create-react-app project with https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript  link but I dont have the tsconfig.json file created for me which the link claims that it would be created for me when I run the above command. Anyone faced this before ?

Comment: @codestruggle What do you mean by "the above command"? It should get generated when you run `npm start`, I think.

Comment: @codestruggle In that case I think you best post a new question - no idea what could be wrong with just this information :/

Comment: Shouldn't you save it in --save-dev?

Comment: @ArturCarvalho The CRA doesn't use `--save-dev`, because the distinction is primarily relevant for Node libraries: `devDependencies` should not be installed by libraries depending on your package, but other libraries don't usually depend on CRA apps. I therefore used `--save` as well, to maintain consistency with the CRA docs.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to eject a configuration in order to do that.

After ejecting you need to perform the following steps:

1. Add typescript extensions `tsx` and `ts` to the `extensions` table
   in the webpack configs (dev and prod).
2. Add ts-loader. Here is an example

   ```
   {
     test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
     include: paths.appSrc,
     use: [
       {
         loader: require.resolve('ts-loader'),
       },
     ],
   },
   ```
3. Change eslint to tslint
4. Add source-map-loader to get a possibility to debug Typescript files.

   ```
   {
     test: /\.js$/,
     loader: require.resolve('source-map-loader'),
     enforce: 'pre',
     include: paths.appSrc,
   }
   ```
5. Create a Typescript config file and remember to set `allowJs` to
   true.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not sure but I think that currently the webpack is managed by react-scripts, because I don't have webpack config in my project. When I eject than I'll have the webpack config files?

Comment: yes, that's why you need to perform eject. If you can wait. the next Babel version will support Typescript out of the box and probably it will be possible to migrate without ejecting. Unfortunately there is no release date for Babel v7 :( but there is available a beta version

Comment: I used this approach as I was working on an existing codebase. I'd like to add that the config files and in other areas of the code you will need to change references to point to .ts/tsx files plus some packages are different. The way I solved this was to create a new app using the _--scripts-version=react-script-ts_ flag and then compare the files in there.

Answer (score 2):

1). run

```
npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

or

```
yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest
```

2). Add the tsconfig.json

> run `npx tsc --init`

3). Add this to the tsconfig

```
 "compilerOptions": {

"jsx": "react-jsx", // this line
```

Now you can integrate `tsx` into an existing project

Comment: It was the 2 latter steps that enabled import of `.tsx` files.

Answer (score 0):

1). run

`npm install --save typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`

or

`yarn add typescript @types/node @types/react @types/react-dom @types/jest`

2). Rename any file to be a TypeScript file (e.g. src/index.js to src/index.tsx)

3). run `npm i @types/react-dom @types/react-redux @types/react-router-dom`

4). Restart your development server!

enjoy :)