# How to migrate ejected React app to TypeScript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have ejected React project and me need integrate Typescript to him. 
How can I do this?

Comment: Please check this, this might show you a lead  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47508564/migrating-create-react-app-from-javascript-to-typescript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create-react-app` already has support for Typescript, if you didn't use the flag `--typescript` when creating your app, you can just install some new dependencies and change the extensions of your files to `ts` or `tsx` to put it to work, the rest is basically configured on Webpack.

Dependencies to install: `typescript`, `@types/react`, `@types/react-dom`, `@types/node`.

You can find more information here: https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-typescript